# Prove there are $75$ ways to put five different fish in three buckets s.t. two buckets are identical and no bucket is empty

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Let $\{\}_1, \{\}_2, \{\}_3$ stand for three distinct buckets. The number of onto functions is given by $n!S(k, n)$ where $S(k, n)$ is a Stirling Number of the Second Kind. So, $3!S(5, 3)$ is a number of ways to distribute five distinct fish into three different buckets with none empty. But this number counts situations like $\{\text{bass}\}_1, \{\text{trout, salmon}\}_2, \{\text{sardine, herring}\}_3$ and $\{\text{trout, salmon}\}_1, \{\text{bass}\}_2, \{\text{sardine, herring}\}_3$ as distinct even though two out of three buckets are identical. We need to divide out the redundant permutation meaning the final answer looks like $\displaystyle{\frac{3!S(5, 3)}{2!} = 75}$. Does it make sense to you? Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is correct - assuming you mean two of the three buckets are given to be identical (not their contents, but the buckets themselves, e.g. they are both red while the remaining bucket is green).